# bash: npm: command not found in Debian 9

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, debian

I am using Debian 9.2. I cannot install the right version of NodeJS, nor does it seem I can install NPM at all.

I ran this from the terminal:

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo bash -
```

The terminal had this output:

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js v9.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:4 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                             
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                        
Hit:7 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                            
Ign:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                         
Hit:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                      
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic Release
Hit:12 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en_US
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en_US
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Then I ran `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`.

Output for `node -v`:

```
bash: node: command not found
```

Output for `nodejs -v`:

```
v4.8.2
```

Output for `npm -v`:

```
bash: npm: command not found
```

How do I install the right version of NodeJS and NPM on Debian 9.2?

Comment: Wrong site, try https://serverfault.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you done anything else to customise your OS install? The errors in your output are pointing to having set up an unreleased version of Ubuntu (18.04 Bionic Beaver).

Comment: Still having this issue. Strange that it's seems to be so uncommon, since NPM is so commonly used.

Comment: Turns out I was missing gunpg which caused the install process to silently fail.

Answer (score 0):

when installing node on linux, npm does not come packaged with it, like on windows. Try -> sudo apt-get install npm , then give it a shot.

Comment: You just get "Unable to locate package npm"

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems.  This finally worked for me.  I was also having problems with gpg keys being added.  No idea if that was the issue, but this was my set of steps leading to a proper install of node v10.4.0 on Debian stretch.  This is my first-ish attempt to respond to one of these.  Hope I'm doing it right.

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/trusted.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.bak
```

Then via nodesource instructions for debian

```
# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

now $"node -v" and "npm version" works